# Unable to open keyboard when checking MediaQuery of bottom insets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I'm trying to check if the keyboard is visible after tapping on the TextFormField by calling:

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0) {
...
}
```

but as soon as I have this MediaQuery call in my code, the Keyboard doesn't even open anymore after tapping on the TextFormField...

**Edited:**
This is what happens when tapping on the TextFormField:

[image: ScreenRecording of Keyboard bug]

I added the code of the page which causes this faulty behavior:

```
class LearnPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int topicId;
  final String topicName;

  LearnPage(this.topicId, this.topicName);

  @override
  _LearnPageState createState() => _LearnPageState();
}

class _LearnPageState extends State<LearnPage> {
  final mainCaardIndex = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  PageController _mainCaardController;
  PageController _inputCaardController;

  List<CaardM> caards;
  List<PageM> mainCaardList = [];
  List<List<PageM>> inputCaardList = [];
  List<List<TextEditingController>> textControllers = [];

  Future<void> async_init() async {
    List<CaardM> caardList =
        await DatabaseProviderCaard.db.getCaards(widget.topicId);
    caards = caardList;
    setState(() {});
  }

  bool _keyboardIsVisible() {
    return !(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0.0);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    async_init();
    _mainCaardController = PageController();
    _inputCaardController = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _mainCaardController.dispose();
    _inputCaardController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.topicName,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          !_keyboardIsVisible()
          ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
              tooltip: 'Validate',
              onPressed: validate,
            )
           : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_hide),
              onPressed: () {
                FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getMainContent(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshotMain) {
                if (snapshotMain.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return PageView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshotMain.data,
                    controller: _mainCaardController,
                    onPageChanged: (position) {
                      mainCaardIndex.value = position;
                      mainCaardIndex.notifyListeners();
                      _inputCaardController.jumpToPage(0);
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                      return LearnMainCaard(
                        mainCaardList[position].title,
                        mainCaardList[position].content,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getInputContent(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshotInput) {
                if (snapshotInput.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: mainCaardIndex,
                    builder: (context, value, _) {
                      return PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshotInput.data,
                        controller: _inputCaardController,

                        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                          return LearnInputCaard(
                            inputCaardList[mainCaardIndex.value][position].title,
                            textControllers[mainCaardIndex.value][position],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<int> getMainContent() async {
    List<PageM> caardPages;
    mainCaardList.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < caards.length; i++) {
      caardPages = await DatabaseProviderPage.db.getPages(caards[i].id);
      if (caards[i].pageAmount > 1) {
        mainCaardList.add(caardPages[0]);
      }
    }
    return mainCaardList.length;
  }

  Future<int> getInputContent() async {
    List<PageM> caardPages = [];
    List<PageM> list = [];
    inputCaardList.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < caards.length; i++) {
      caardPages = await DatabaseProviderPage.db.getPages(caards[i].id);
      if (caards[i].pageAmount > 1) {
        addController(caards[i].pageAmount - 1);
        list = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < caardPages.length; i++) {
          list.add(caardPages[i]);
        }
        inputCaardList.add(list);
      }
    }
    return inputCaardList[mainCaardIndex.value].length;
  }

  void addController(int controllerAmount) {
    List<TextEditingController> currentTextControllers = [];
    print('addController called');
    currentTextControllers.clear();
    currentTextControllers = List.generate(
        controllerAmount, (index) => TextEditingController()
    );

    textControllers.add(currentTextControllers);
  }
```

And here the LearnInputCaard widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LearnInputCaard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final TextEditingController textController;
  LearnInputCaard(
      this.title,
      this.textController,
      );

  @override
  _LearnInputCaardState createState() => _LearnInputCaardState();
}

class _LearnInputCaardState extends State<LearnInputCaard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        color: Colors.amberAccent.shade100,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.black38,),
              Expanded(
                flex: 10,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: widget.textController,
                    maxLines: 30,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter content",
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: any specific reason to do that because when you have onTaped on textformfield the keyboard is opened.

Comment: it's to display an iconbutton which hides the keyboard, when the keyboard is open @AbhishekGhaskata

Comment: have you given the form key `static GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();`?

Comment: also, refer to this as well https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20042
Thanks.

Comment: providing a formKey didn't solve the problem @AbhishekGhaskata

Comment: added some code for maybe better understanding of my problem @AbhishekGhaskata

Comment: sorry, but I can not see any `TextFormField` here.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to add the LearnInputCaard widget which contains the textfield... anyway I edited the question and added this widget to my code :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to check `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0.0`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Keyboard Visibility Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _keyboardIsVisible()
                  ? Text(
                      "Keyboard is visible",
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .display1
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.blue),
                    )
                  : RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "Keyboard is ",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .display1
                              .copyWith(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "not ",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .display1
                              .copyWith(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "visible",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .display1
                              .copyWith(color: Colors.blue),
                        )
                      ]),
                    ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200.0,
                child: TextField(
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  bool _keyboardIsVisible() {
    return !(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0.0);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I´m looking for a way to check for the visibility of keyboard not for a way to hide it.

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I meant... take a look at my edited question, where I added a gif for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the context from the parent widget.

If you call:

```
MediaQuery.of(context);
```

in the same widget where your forms are, you shouldn't get this behavior.

You need to define a `GlobalKey<FormState>` in your highest widget and pass this one down. Then it works. I defined it first in my SafeArea and therefore it failed and I had the same problem with the keyboard.

Here are some snippets of my code. I have a PageController and use two different forms on my two pages.

```
class OnboardingScaffold extends HookConsumerWidget {
  OnboardingScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // here you define your GlobalKeys
  final _formKeyLogin = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _formKeyApply = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final controller = usePageController();

    bool isKeyboard = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: !isKeyboard
            ? const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80)
            : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
        child: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            // here you pass these keys into your child Widget
            LoginSafeArea(
              formKey: _formKeyLogin,
            ),
            ApplySafeArea(
              formKey: _formKeyApply,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: !isKeyboard
          ? Container(height: 80)
          : Container(height: 0),
    );
  }
}
```

The child Widget should contain a Form Widget:

```
class LoginSafeArea extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const LoginSafeArea({Key? key, required this.formKey}) : super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const EmailFieldWidget(),
                const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                const PasswordFieldWidget(),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                LoginButtonWidget(
                  formKey: formKey,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```